# Python: how to locate a missing delimiter and append it to a text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python and stuck on what I assume is a trivial problem. I am trying to add a delimiter // to the end of each line in a text file when that delimiter doesn't exist for that line.

Example text file 'example.txt':

```
A string of information that does not require the delimiter
95 full !oe, !oeha //
96 new  kaba
100 name    !uo5 //
```

In this example text file, I wish to add // to the end of the line beginning with 96. My strategy is to locate those lines that require the delimiter (i.e., a line that begins with a number), test to see if // exists, and if not then to append // to the end of that line. My code is as follows:

```
import re
infile = open("example.txt", 'r+w')

for line in infile:
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)\s+\w+\s+([^/]+)', line)
    if m:
        test = line.find('//')
        if test == -1:
            infile.write(line + ' // \n')
        continue
```

The output of my example.txt file looks like this:

```
A string of information that does not require the delimiter
95 full !oe, !oeha //
96 new  kaba
100 name    !uo5 //
96 new  kaba
 //
```

Why does `infile.write(line + ' // \n')` append a new line to the .txt file rather than replace the line lacking a delimiter? Furthermore, why doesn't the delimiter // appear on the same line?

I've experimented using `infile.replace(line, line + ' // \n')` in place of `infile.write(line + ' // \n')` but get the error message `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

Comment: It apears at new line because the line is already delimited by a `\n` wich is read to the `line` variable in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simplify the code a lot by using `re.sub` function.

```
^(\d+.*)(?<!//)$
```

Example usage:

```
>>> file = open('input', 'r')
>>> for line in file:
...     print re.sub(r'^(\d+.*)(?<!//)$', r'\1//', line),
```

Would produce an output as

```
A string of information that does not require the delimiter
95 full !oe, !oeha //
96 new  kaba//
100 name    !uo5 //
```

**Regex**

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `\d+` Matches any number of strings. Anchor ensures that the line begins with a digit
- `.*` matches anything till the end of the line
- `(?<!//)` negative lookbehind. asserts that the end of string, `$` is not presceded by a `//`
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you pointing out the `re.sub()` function.

Comment: @user3731769 you are welcome. Glad to hear I was of some use :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=\d+(?:(?!\/\/).)*$)(.*)
```

Try this.Replace by `\1 //`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/13

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^(?=\d+(?:(?!\/\/).)*$)(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"A string of information that does not require the delimiter\n95 full !oe, !oeha //\n96 new kaba\n100 name !uo5 //\n100 name !uo5 "
subst = u"\1 //"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Replace `test_str` by file.read().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, if the line starts with a digit/digits and does not end with `"//"` just strip the newline add a `"//\n"` to the end, reopen in `w` mode to overwrite and write the updated lines.

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
         if line.split()[0].isdigit() and not line.rstrip().endswith("//"):
            lines[ind] = line.rstrip() + " //\n"
    with open("example.txt","w") as f1:
        for line in lines:
            f1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a different file for output rather than input, and manually overwrite afterwords if you really need to replace it.  I did the following in Python 2.7:

```
import re

# Open an output file distinct from the input file
infile = open("example.txt", 'r')
outfile = open("output.txt", 'w')

for line in infile:
    # Newline already present in input line - rstrip() to kill it
    result = line.rstrip()
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)\s+\w+\s+([^/]+)', result)
    if m:
        test = result.find('//')
        if test == -1:

            # Add the delimiter
            result += ' //'

    # Just write the original line if no changes were needed
    outfile.write(result + "\n")

# Close the streams
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks rchang. I actually am using a different file for the output, but tried to simplify my code for exposition. I solved my problem using some of the points you made, so thanks!